# How to apply filters on Shopware sw_include (for example: |sw_sanitize)

Tags: twig, shopware, shopware6, twig-filter

Is there a way to use filters on the sw_include twig function?

This works:

```
{% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/component/captcha/%s.html.twig'|format(capchaKey)...
```

I'd like to remove all tags from the include. Based on twig docu this should work:

```
{{ include('template.html')|striptags }}
```

However this does not throw any errors, but also does not apply the filter:

```
{% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/component/delivery-information.html.twig'|sw_sanitize %}
```

Answer (score 3):

The filters `striptags` and `sw_sanitize` work fairly different. `striptags` removes all html tags, but **keeps** their content. `sw_santitize` completely removes *some* specific tags that could potentially be harmful (like `<script>`) and removes them **including** their contents. This is why `sw_sanitize` may seem to you like it doesn't do anything, because it will keep "harmless" tags like `<div>`, `<a>` and some others intact.

When I tested it, the `striptags` filter *actually* didn't work applied to  `sw_include` directly. You may want to use `set` to capture the contents of an include and then apply the filter on the variable.

```
{% set foo %}
    {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/component/delivery-information.html.twig' %}
{% endset %}
{{ foo|striptags }}
```